# Creating url from the cloudfront aws

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have my js files which I have uploaded into the Amazon S3 and linked it with the Cloudfront.

I got a url something like this :

```
dxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
```

But opening that url in my browser ( I'm getting an error ) :

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>xxxxxx</RequestId>
<HostId>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
</HostId>
</Error>
```

But what I want actually is to use the url and add them to my webpage. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the ACLs on your S3 objects so that they're world readable. By default they're not.

Comment: Thanks that works, the access denied error went off. Now it shows only the xml file. But what I want to show is the js that I uploaded into my s3 bucket.

Comment: The URL you've pasted above doesn't contain a path to the actual .js file. Find the full path of your .js file and add it to the end of your dxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net name. For example: `http://dxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/my.js`